# Put the URL parameter into a XSL variable

Tags: xslt

I have a XSL-XML page that opens with a certain url for example http://www.example.xml
sometimes the URL has some parameters
for example http://www.example.xml?pLanguage=nl&source=enews

I want to extract the source parameter from the URL and put it into a xsl:variable.

I thought to do it with javascript with the window.top.location.search.substring(1); put I don't know how to put the result into a xsl:variable.

can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

XSLT processors usually provide a facility to set the values of global parameters in the stylesheet. For example, the [`XSLTProcessor` in Gecko](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/The_XSLT_JavaScript_Interface_in_Gecko/Setting_Parameters).

Here is an example that should work on Gecko-based browsers (e.g. FireFox).

First you need a stylesheet with xsl:param names.

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<!-- file: /xslt-stylesheet.xsl -->
<xsl:param name="pLanguage"></xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="source"></xsl:param>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <root>
    <pLanguage><xsl:value-of select="$pLanguage"/></pLanguage>
    <source><xsl:value-of select="$source"/></source>
   </root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Then put this javascript in your html file for the browser to interpret:

```js
// Var to hold the transformed document
var transformeddoc = null;
// source document to transform. We'll use document.body as an easy example.
var sourcedoc = document.body;
// extract parameters from the window's query string
var params = extractparams(window.location.search);
// create an xslt processor
var xsltproc = new XSLTProcessor();
// set stylesheet paramaters
xsltproc.setParameter(null, 'pLanguage', params.pLanguage);
xsltproc.setParameter(null, 'source', params.source);
// load xslt document
var xslt = document.implementation.createDocument("", "test", null);
xslt.addEventListener("load", processXslt, false);
xslt.load("/xslt-stylesheet.xsl");

// after document is loaded, perform the transform
function processXslt() {
    xsltproc.importStylesheet(xslt);
    transformeddoc = xsltproc.transformToDocument(sourcedoc);
    // transformeddoc is now a DOM of this xml:
    // <root><pLanguage>pl</pLanguage><source>sc</source></root>
}

function extractparams(querystring) {
    var params = {'pLanguage':'', 'source':''};
    var qs = querystring.replace(/^\?/, '');
    qs = qs.split('&');
    for (var i=0, kv; i<qs.length; i++) {
        kv = qs[i].split('=');
        if (kv.length===2 && kv[0] in params) {
            params[kv[0]] = kv[1];
        }
    }
    return params;
}
```

Comment: With parameter I didn't meant xsl:param. I meant I meant the parameter of the URL. In  http://www.example.xml?pLanguage=nl&source=enews I mean the parameters pLanguage and source.

Comment: I have expanded the answer with an example, but the same principle applies to "put the result into an xsl:variable."